# Train and test split data with features

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, training-data

Load the Iris dataset from sklearn. Split the dataset into training and testing parts. Pick 2 of the 4 features.
I write this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.33,random_state=42)
```

But I didn't understand "Pick 2 of the 4 features". Is that means test_size and random_state? Or is it something different?

Comment: What do you mean with "Pick 2 of the 4 features" ? Where were you asked to pick two? Also, I'm no expert, but it may be referring to the four features of [this Iris dataset](http://www.lac.inpe.br/~rafael.santos/Docs/CAP394/WholeStory-Iris.html) (length, width, sepals, petals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iris dataset has petal length,petal width,sepal length,sepal width as 4 features.
Pick 2 of the 4 feature means take two of those 4 features in your training model.
I don't know why you want to do that as using all four feature makes model more accurate

Comment: I want to estimate and graph densities for existing classes using the Gaussian Mixture Model. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

The test size is a ratio. For example if the `test_size = 0.33`, then 33% of the data will be the test data and the remaining 67% will be the train data.

The random state is the seed that is produced for sampling taking the test and training data randomly from the whole data set (fixed value like `42` is used when you need to ensure repeatibility). You can study in detail the theory behind random number creation from a seed in computer science that leads to a random number.